# Visual Studio 15.3.1 can't find core DLLs after update

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm getting the runtime error:

`InvalidOperationException: Can not find assembly file mscorlib.dll at '...\bin\Debug\net462\refs,...\bin\Debug\net462\'`

This had not been a problem until I updated to version 15.3.1 this morning, and installed the .Net Core 2.0 SDK.

The DLL's are present in my `~\.nuget\packages folder`. I'd had the same issue with the "Microsoft.Csharp.dll" assembly until I copied and pasted it into the stated folder.

---

I tried specifying to use .Net Core 1.1.0 via a `global.json` file, but then I get the build error:

> The version of Microsoft.NET.Sdk used by this project is insufficient to support references to libraries targeting .NET Standard 1.5 or higher.  Please install version 2.0 or higher of the .NET Core SDK.

This error goes away if I clean the solution then restore Nuget packages **via Command Line**- not via the GUI. However it comes back if I change the version of a nuget package.

Comment: Just finished the update. Reading this with the most excellent timing possible.

Comment: OK I appear to have fixed this by nuking all the bin and obj directories, restoring NuGet packages and rebuilding. That's not really an *answer* though...

Comment: Also, I'm sorry for suggesting the obvious, but did you try removing and adding the assemblies again? Also, write 'using' statements in the file throwing the error to update intellisense and then remove them if they're unecessary.

Comment: @Tiramonium yeah deleting the obj & bin folders and doing a nuget restore gets it running at least. But it breaks again as soon as I change a version of a nuget package. (Annoyingly, I was meant to be testing a new version of an internal nuget package today...)

Comment: But as far as I know it really is recommended to do a full recompilation when you change a reference or package version. You don't need to go to the project folder and erase the files manually, "Clean solution" does that for you.

Comment: I've just had the same thing, installed the SDK 2.0 which has lead to further problems... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45803126/visual-studio-update-2017-15-3-1-forces-asp-net-core-sdk-2-0-which-then-doesnt

Comment: I've discovered that it only gets running again if I restore Nuget packages via command line- doing it via the GUI gives me the _can't find Microsoft.CSharp.dll_ message

Comment: @Jess have you tried adding `<DependsOnNETStandard>netstandard1.5</DependsOnNETStandard>` to your csproj file?

Comment: @RemarkLima Hi, I tried it and I'm in a similar situation- I get an error, but if I delete _obj_ and _bin_ and restore nuget by command line, runs. Otherwise I get _The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'._

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45795738/visual-studio-15-3-1-cant-find-core-dlls-after-update#comment78599552_45795738) error also comes back after restarting Visual Studio

Answer (score 3):

OK, this seem slightly different to my issue here: [Visual Studio update 2017 15.3.1 forces ASP.NET Core SDK 2.0, which then doesn't find "reference assemblies"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45803126/visual-studio-update-2017-15-3-1-forces-asp-net-core-sdk-2-0-which-then-doesnt)

If you install the SDK 2.0 from https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core

You will then "probably" be able to build and run the project again but you'll be back to having the missing `Microsoft.CSharp.dll` / `mscorelib.dll` error.

If you then make sure the dependency is correct for the netstandard version:

```
<DependsOnNETStandard>netstandard1.5</DependsOnNETStandard>
```

See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard for the right version for you. My project is using core 1.1 targeting the full framework 4.6.1 and targeting `netstandard1.6` has worked for me.

The final piece of the puzzel, was found on the GitHub issues here: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1488

Add the following to your references in the `.csproj` file:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel" Version="2.0.0" />
```

This will then build the project as a 1.1 project, but using the 2.0 SDK (which from what I can tell, it's supposed to do!). I can now run the project, update packages and generally got on with my work!

Comment: Thanks, I've tried adding the 2.0 dependency model, will try it out this morning and hope the issues are resolved...

Comment: That didn't seem to do it, still reliant on the workarounds :(

Comment: Is that after installing the SDK 2.0? As for me, it built but threw the error around the missing `Microsoft.CSharp.dll`. Is it the same errors?