# Visual Studio update 2017 15.3.1 forces ASP.NET Core SDK 2.0, which then doesn't find "reference assemblies"

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

Related to this question:
[Visual Studio 15.3.1 can't find core DLLs after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45795738/visual-studio-15-3-1-cant-find-core-dlls-after-update)

I've had to do the same process, a corrupt VS settings meant I ran the installer and updated VS 2017 to 15.3.1. Since then, my main project wouldn't run without having the .NET Core SDK 2.0 installed, like in the referenced question above.

I've installed the SDK 2.0, which resolved the error, the project builds and run but then immediately throws `InvalidOperationException: Can not find assembly file Microsoft.CSharp.dll at 'build paths'`

If I drop that DLL from my `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1` directory (I'm using a .NET Core app targeting the full framework 4.6.1) into the bin folder, it then moves onto `mscorelib.dll` that's missing, and then on-and-on.

Before just dumping the whole lot into the bin output folder, I'm assuming that for some reason the new setup doesn't find the new SDK files and / or reference assemblies folder?

Is there a fix for this? That will also reflect into production environments.

---

There's the same issue on GitHub here: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/2129 which links to https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1488

The issue is the same, nothing has been upgraded - only VS updated to 15.3.1, which has then thrown the `The version of Microsoft.NET.Sdk used by this project is insufficient to support references to libraries targeting .NET Standard 1.5 or higher. Please install version 2.0 or higher of the .NET Core SDK.` error **with no other changes to the project**

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't forces anything, it's you who updated your projects to ASP.NET Core 2.0 or .NET Core 2.0. There is no automatic migration or anything like that. You probably have bad dependencies, since the errors sound like you had .NET COre project before and upgraded that to .NET Core 2.0 and your dependencies have non-`netcoreapp2.0`/`netstandard2.0` dependencies. You **can't use .NET 4.5** libraries that use API which is not defined in netstandard2.0/netcoreapp2.0. You can reference them, but you must be 100% certain they don't use any unavailable APIs

Comment: @Tseng - The project and all references are still .net core 1.1 - there's nothing that targets 2.0. The error was `The version of Microsoft.NET.Sdk used by this project is insufficient to support references to libraries targeting .NET Standard 1.5 or higher. Please install version 2.0 or higher of the .NET Core SDK.` - and without any modification to the project (I've just updated VS 2017 to 15.3.1 on my laptop) that error is thrown. That leads me to then install the .NET Core SDK 2.0 and again without any modifications, the above happens.

Comment: and you did a nuget/dotnet restore?

Comment: Yep, also tried to delete the bin and obj folders, then rebuild with no joy either...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After spending the day on this, as per the linked GitHub issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1488 the current solution is to add the following to your `.csproj` file, in the main `<PropertyGroup>` node:

```
<DependsOnNETStandard>netstandard1.5</DependsOnNETStandard>
```

There's some more information on what to target here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

It may be only for .netcore projects, targeting the full framework (4.6.1 in this case), when you update to VS 2017 15.3 and above.

If a better fix comes along, I'll update the answer to reflect it.